# global variable in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, global-variables

In PHP, I used to define some variables in my `header.php` and use them in all my pages.  How can I have something like that in Laravel?

I am not talking about `View::share('xx', 'xx' );`

Assume I want to have a variable which holds a number in it and I need this number inside all my controllers to calculate something.

Comment: I don't know th laravel, but to achieve this you may always create a singleton registry class. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Sounds like a good candidate for a [configuration file](http://laravel.com/docs/configuration).

Create a new one, let's call it `calculations.php`:

**Laravel ~4ish:**

```
app
    config
        calculations.php
```

**Laravel 5,6,7+:**

```
config
    calculations.php
```

Then put stuff in the new config file:

```
<?php return [ 'some_key' => 42 ];
```

Then retrieve the config in your code somewhere (note the file name becomes a "namespace" of sorts for the config item):

```
echo Config::get('calculations.some_key'); // 42 in Laravel ~4
echo config('calculations.some_key'); // 42 in Laravel ~5,6,7+
```

Comment: Excellent. Didn't know you could do it this way :-)

Comment: Incredibly elegant. Best answer by far.

Comment: @NathanSiafa It's not anymore, it was 5 years ago. The path is now just `config/calculations.php`.

Comment: is this still valid for Laravel 6 ?

Answer (score 5):

Set a property on the `BaseController`, which should be located in your `controllers` directory.

Your controllers should extend the `BaseController` class and thus inherit its properties.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [View Composers](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/views#view-composers)

And instead of using the boot method described in the docs you could use:

```
public function boot()
{
    // Using class based composers...
    view()->composer(
        '*', 'App\Http\ViewComposers\ProfileComposer'
    );

    // Using Closure based composers...
    view()->composer('*', function ($view) {

    });
}
```

That would render whatever variables you declare with

```
$view->with('yourVariableName', 'yourVariableValue');
```

to all the views in your app.

Here is a full example of how I used this in one of my projects.

**app/Providers/ComposerServiceProvider.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ComposerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
     /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        view()->composer(
            '*', 'App\Http\ViewComposers\UserComposer'
        );
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

**app/Http/ViewComposers/UserComposer.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\ViewComposers;

use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;

class UserComposer
{

    protected $auth;

    public function __construct(Guard $auth)
    {
        // Dependencies automatically resolved by service container...
        $this->auth = $auth;
    }

    public function compose(View $view)
    {
        $view->with('loggedInUser', $this->auth->user());
    }
}
```

Just remember that because you declared a new service provider it needs to be included in the 'providers' array in **config/app.php**

Answer (score 0):

You can define them in your `app\Http\Controllers\Controller.php` , for example:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;

class Controller extends BaseController
{
    public $test = 'something';

    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;
}
```

Then afterwards in all of your controllers, you can access this property by doing:

`$this->test;`